# Check mysql database state periodically from java

Tags: mysql

I am new to this MySQL concepts.i want to check the MySQL database periodically whether its working properly or not from java.Is there any simple way to check this.

Comment: What do you mean by working properly? and you are not new to Mysql if you are not new to RDBMS

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.working properly means like Mysql is killed in middle of execution of a query or database becoming unstable at some times ..etc.. also i am new to the to RDBM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by connecting to your database via JDBC. If the connection succeeds, then you know that the database is up and running. 
If it doesn't succeed, the database may still be up of course - it could be something else like network connectivity, but still - you know that there's some problem you should check so this is a simple way to monitor.

If you're looking for more elaborate testing (like @shakti-singh commented - it depends on what you mean by working properly), then you can create a synthetic transaction - write code that queries something in the same way that your application does and ensure that you get the expected results. (Google "synthetic transactions" for more information).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.working properly means like Mysql is killed in middle of execution of a query or database becoming unstable at some times ..etc